# Animator does not have an AnimatorController

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm very confused, I try to play animation when hitting a certain object, the hit is detected correctly (the attempt debug) and after that I try to play animation that exists on the object (via the Animator)
[image]

yet it tells me Animator does not have an AnimatorController and wont play the animation. Clearly there is an AnimatorController, and he is in fact working correctly:
[image]

my code:

```
  if (d.name == "furnacedef")
        {
            Debug.Log("attempt");
            Animator b= d.model.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
            b.Play("burning");

        }
```

Comment: Potentially related, but maybe not. Don't ignore that error message in your console. Don't use `DestroyImmediate` at runtime, use `Destroy`. This could cause further problems.

Comment: What kind of object is 'd'? If the animator is attached as part of the hierarchy of 'd', try xxx.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>() instead. If d is a transform, d.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>() should works. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WalterPalladino d is a prefab gameobject, animator is on him not on children, children don't have animators

Comment: The method GetComponentInChildren search parent and children too.

Comment: @WalterPalladino attempted it now, didn't work..

Comment: Can you try to add a small script to the prefab where an Awake method trying to get the Animator component? Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry. Found out the bug, the .model was the prefab and not the gameobject. thanks for your help